# how to show gif image while uploading using jquery form plugin in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have file upload using jquery form plugin as

```
$(function() {

        $("#Form").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Upload/Index",
            success: function(result) {
                $('#MyGrid').append('<tr><td><a href="#">result</a></td></tr>');

            },
            beforeSubmit: function() {

            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

and my form as

```
<form id="Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br />
    <input type="file" name="addedFile" id="addedFile"  />
    <br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Now i want to show loading gif image from user clicks submit button to till i get result to success function. how can i do that .

thanks,

michaeld

Comment: There's really no need to use the form plugin any more, it's just as simple using jQuery's $.ajax methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert an `img` element into the DOM (I assume this would go in the `beforeSubmit` function):

```
// doesn't have to be added to the body;
// wherever you want it is cool
$('<img id="loadingGif" src="path/load.gif" />').appendTo('body');
```

Then you can just use CSS to position it absolutely or whatever else you'd like to do.

Then, on `error` or `success`, you can remove the image:

```
$('#loadingGif').remove();
```

You could make it a little more efficient by only building the element once, and then simply adding/removing from the DOM, but this is a basic start.

Comment: this jquery image snippet is not showing . is that correct, i tried appending to form, it not showed

Answer (score 3):

You can have a absolutely positioned container on the page and show/hide it whenever required.

Wroking **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMu4z/2/)**.

Here I have use a loading text you can replace it by appropriate image, as per your requirement you can modify the styles also.

**Markup**

```
<div class="loading">
    <br /><br />
    <div>Loading...</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.loading{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.loading div{
    margin: auto 0px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Js**

```
function showLoading(){
  var $loading = $(".loading");
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  var windowW = $(window).width();

  $loading.css({
    position:"fixed",
    left: ((windowW - $loading.outerWidth())/2 + $(document).scrollLeft()),
    top: ((windowH - $loading.outerHeight())/2 + $(document).scrollTop())
  }).show();
}

function hideLoading(){
   $(".loading").hide();
}


$(function() {

        showLoading();

        $("#Form").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Upload/Index",
            success: function(result) {
                hideLoading();
                $('#MyGrid').append('<tr><td><a href="#">result</a></td></tr>');

            },
            beforeSubmit: function() {

            },
            error: function(response) {
                hideLoading();
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: +1 for having working demo on jsfiddle.  This is the way I've often done it in the past.

Comment: @michael - Did you take a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's `blockUI` plugin. [reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos).

```
$(function() {

        $("#Form").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Upload/Index",
            success: function(result) {
                $('#MyGrid').append('<tr><td><a href="#">result</a></td></tr>');
                    $.unblockUI();
            },
            beforeSubmit: function() {
                $.blockUI({ 
                   message: $('#displayBox'), 
                   css: { 
                       top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                       left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                       width: '400px' 
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```