# How to preview a image before uploading it to the server?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form that will adding the product to the online store, and contains this many fields

1) Product Name

2) Product Code

3) Product Description

4) Product Price

5) Product Image

now i wanted that while user/admin select a image using file upload control of asp.net, after selecting product image that will be displayed in image control before the user will upload that to the server.

all i need is to preview that image before it will uploaded to the server, it will be by using any of these javascript, jquery, Ajax or c#

please help me...

Thank in Advance.
Tejas Vaishnav

Comment: Use jQuery plugins. Reference thread -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088299/how-to-show-gif-image-while-uploading-using-jquery-form-plugin-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @adatapost How does linked thread refers to **previewing** image before upload?

Comment: Here is an [SO search for this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=preview+getasdataurl)

Answer (score 2):

C# executes on the server so the image has to be already there.

Javascript and jQuery run client-side so you could have more luck with these two ( in fact JQuery is just a JS library on top of the JS engine in the browser ).

Why don't you use the preview feature of the browser's open/select file dialog anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You need a script that uses a dataURI for Gecko...

This may not work with default security from a web server but does work if you load the page from your harddisk

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/image-upload-preview.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot quiet possibly do it just using JavaScript unless you use Flash or some other ActiveX plugins. It is because you cannot access the client machines resources without permission due to security reasons. You can only upload on the server and preview it. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Question is about previewing image **before** uploading it.

Comment: Whoever can you remove the down vote, I have modified my answer?

Answer (score -2):

Quick googling didn't show any promissing results (at least one working in cross-browser manner). Your best shot is using Flash (version > 10, since it was the first version that enables you to access local files picked by user). It can be simple Flash (or Flex) application, you can find many examples of manipulating/showing user selected files **before** sending them to the server. [**Here**](http://e-fotos.pl/zamowienie/szczegoly/) you can find example of such application (made by me). You can pick image from your local disk and it is displayed / can be manipulated all before uploading it to the server.

Check the simple example of [previewing an image before uploading it](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/25/previewing-an-image-before-uploading-it-using-the-filereference-class-in-flash-player-10/) (Flex)