# How to show preview of image being uploaded before actually sending it to server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a FileUpload control in my aspx page and I want to display the image selected before postback so that user confirms the image to upload.

Comment: If this was possible through pure html, then you would have seen this features in social networking site many days earlier. Needs to post data before shoing the image preview.

Comment: it *might* be possible with HTML5, though... I'm thinking something like the file drop-zone in gmail

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preview a image before uploading it to the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242473/how-to-preview-a-image-before-uploading-it-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this AJAX Control Toolkit Control for Image Confirmation.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: you can store image in temp directory and display it in <image> tag. if user re-upload the image you have to remove that image and store new one and display in  <image> tag. both contains in Update Panel.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for would require a pure client-side solution, which I do not think is possible since they do not have access to the file system(under normal circumstances).

Note that using AJAX requires actually sending the file to the server first.

Answer (score 1):

This Can be done VIA HTML5 now,

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

When the upload is selected you want to read the file with

readAsBinaryString

Then you would need to turn that binary to Base64 so you could display it on the page,

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Then you will need to put it into an img tag on the in the src E.G

```
<img src="data:{image/mime_type};base64,{base64_binary_data}" width="100" height="100" />
```

Where {image/mime_type} is the mime type of the image they have uploaded E.G image/png, image/jpg

And {base64_binary_data} is the readAsBinaryString after it's gone though the base64 conversion

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible through HTML. But it may be possible using flash/silverlight.

I say this because I remember coming across an issue when I wanted to know up front how big a file was before the user uploaded it. Html doesn't give you the ability to know this, the user must upload the whole file before you can say how big it is.

However, the workaround was to use flash because flash seems to have permissions to grab data about a file from the local disk before sending it to the server (after the user selects the file of course). Since it can grab the filename, size, etc then I imagine you'll be able to grab the image data too and then display it.

Comment: Would you please give me hint where to start, I've no idea about using flash

Comment: linkerro has provided a good link, which is what I found after a quick google search. It'd be good to know if it worked ok if you manage to do it..

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to use flash or silverlight to do that.
Here's an article where it's explained how to do that with flash:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/25/previewing-an-image-before-uploading-it-using-the-filereference-class-in-flash-player-10/

Comment: Thanks, but how to do with asp.net?

Comment: You can't do that using only asp.net.